# Lost on VB.Net SQL Insert Query

Tags: vb.net, oledb

So I'm running into a problem, I've finally got the code to pass with no errors, but the Database doesn't actually show the updates.

I've run some code and I think it's going to a .pdb file.  Will it always go there and just use the .mdb file as a template?

```
Private Sub NextButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles NextButton.Click

    Dim count As Integer = 0
    Dim insertSql As String = "INSERT INTO StudentTable(BadgeNo,FirstName,LastName,SAPID,Email,Phone,College) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)"
    Dim connStr As String = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=""C:\Users\larsennicholasg\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SSCLogin\SSCLogin\My Project\SSCStudent.mdb"""
    Using conn As New OleDbConnection(connStr), cmd As New OleDbCommand(insertSql, conn)

        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(BadgeNoTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = FirstNameTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = LastNameTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.Integer).Value = CInt(SAPSIDTextBox.Text)
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = EmailTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = PhoneTextBox.Text
        cmd.Parameters.Add("?", OleDbType.WChar, 255).Value = CollegeComboBox.Text

        conn.Open()
 If (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1) Then 
    MessageBox.Show("Success") 
  Else
    MessageBox.Show("Nerp") 
 End If



        conn.Close()

    End Using


    Me.Hide()
    TestPull.Show()


End Sub
```

Comment: As before, allow that you method of testing the insertion is faulty.  You dont show that code, so we cant tell. A surefire way is to open teh DB in Access and look at it.  Also `.ExecuteNonQuery()` is a function returning the number of rows affected capture/test the return to see if it s 1.

Comment: I've got the DB open in access, it's not effecting it at all.

Comment: Ok, and if `.ExecuteNonQuery` is returning 1 then you are not looking at the same copy in Access as you are using in VB.

Comment: Ok, it's returning 1 according to this code:


            If (cmd.ExecuteNonQuery() = 1) Then
                MessageBox.Show("Success")
            Else
                MessageBox.Show("Nerp")


            End If

Comment: Ok, so I ran some code to check in the program itself, it's registering a new entry every time, but I have seemingly no access to this DB outside of the program.  What could cause that?

Comment: Check for an mdb at `C:\Users\larsennicholasg\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\SSCLogin\SSCLogin\My Project\bin..." the exact location will depend on the project build configuration such as `bin\x86\Debug` if the project is set for x86, Debug. **Build -> Configuration Manager** will tell you where to look.  That is a bad way to specify a User folder, by the way,

Comment: I didn't do it on purpose, what is the standard way of doing it better?